# Getting numbers from one number to another one, without numbers from another array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got 2 variables:

```
const min = 2010;
const max = new Date().getFullYear();
```

And array of years that have to be omitted.

```
const omitYears = [2020, 2019, 2018];
```

What is the best way to get array numbers from `min` to `max` without numbers from `omitYears`:
`2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2021`

Comment: `from min to max without numbers` what this mean?

Comment: `min` and `max` is a variable that I provided.

Comment: is the data sorted? should be the result sorted? what have you tried? what goes wrong?

Comment: SO is not a free code-writing service. What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? A simple `for` loop with a check (e.g. `.indexOf()`) would be enough for this task.

Comment: I was asking about the best way to solve that :) i'll try with for loop then. Thanks

Comment: @DiPix Yes i know, but you're saying you want array numbers from `min` to `max` AND also after that you wrote `without numbers from omitYears` . This don't make sense to me,  Can you please clarify

Comment: Define _"best way"_? And even then this will most likely only generate opinion-based answers -> off-topic

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a generator and get all the values between the given values.

```js
function* getYears(from, to, omit) {
    let n = from;
    while (n <= to) {
        if (!omit.includes(n)) yield n;
        ++n;
    }
}

console.log(...getYears(2010, new Date().getFullYear(), [2020, 2019, 2018]));
```

Comment: No answers so far on your questions (_"is the data sorted? should be the result sorted? what have you tried? what goes wrong?"_), but who cares...

Comment: @Andreas, my answer rely on other answers to give a different view how to tackle the problem. if op answers the comment, i would be happy to write an improvement for this.

Comment: Cool example of generator usage. :) One more question is there any way to replace `from++` somehow, as I have eslitnt rule `no-param-reassign` that not allows me to use that.

Comment: use `let n = from;` and use `n` instead of `from`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of Array.filter and Array.includes.

```js
const min = 2010;
const max = new Date().getFullYear();

const omitYears = [2020, 2019, 2018];

const years = getRange(min, max); // Use lodash.range or something similar here


const yearsWithoutOmitYears = years.filter((year) => {
  return !omitYears.includes(year);
});


/* 
yearsWithoutOmitYears will be [
  2010, 2011, 2012,
  2013, 2014, 2015,
  2016, 2017
] 
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `indexOf` and `for` loop are required

```js
var min = 2010;
var max = new Date().getFullYear();

var omitYears = [2020, 2019, 2018];
var years = [2001, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2021];
var minPos = years.indexOf(min);
var maxPos = years.indexOf(max);


var finalYears = [];
for(minPos; minPos <= maxPos; minPos++){
    if(omitYears.indexOf(years[minPos]) == -1){
finalYears.push(years[minPos]);
    }
} 
console.log(finalYears)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const min = 2010;
const max = new Date().getFullYear();

let array = [];
const omitYears = [2020, 2019, 2018]; 

for(let i = min; i <= max ; i++){
  if(!omitYears.includes(i))
   array.push(i)
}

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const min = 2010;
const max = new Date().getFullYear();

const omitYears = [2020, 2019, 2018];

var years = Array.from(new Array(max - min + 1), (x, i) => i+min);
years = years.filter((year) => !omitYears.includes(year))
```

Create the array and then filter it